# Adding two Xpath with union in PHP function?

Tags: php, xml, xpath

With the code below I show the titles of many RSS. Those RSS must be in the format of `rss->channel->item` where in the `item` you find `title`,`description`, `pubDate` and so on.

My question is how to modify this, so It will **also** accept RSS that are in the format of `feed->entry` where in the `entry` you echo `title`,`content`,`published`?

```
$feeds = array('', '');


// Get all feed entries
$posts = array();
foreach ($feeds as $feed) {

    $xml = simplexml_load_file($feed);
    $posts = array_merge($posts, $xml->xpath('/rss/channel//item'));

}


// Sort feed entries by pubDate (ascending)
usort($posts, 'mysort');


function mysort($x, $y) {
    return strtotime($y->pubDate) - strtotime($x->pubDate);
}

foreach ($posts as $post) {
echo $post->description; // if the rss is in the format of rss->channel->item
echo $post->content; // if the rss is in the format of feed->entry->content then
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I wanted

```
return strtotime(($y->pubDate)?$y->pubDate:$y->published) - 
                  strtotime(($x->pubDate)?$x->pubDate:$x->published);
```

Answer (score 1):

**Use the XPath [*union*](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#node-sets) (`|`) operator**:

```
/rss/channel/item | /rss/feed/entry
```

**For the sort use**:

```
published | pubDate
```

**Explanation**: Union of mutually exclusive sets results in just one of them.

Comment: How do I actually change the function?     `return strtotime($y->pubDate) - strtotime($x->pubDate);`

Comment: I am not familiar with PHP, but it may be something like: `return strtotime($y-> (pubDate | published) ) - strtotime($x->(pubDate | published) ); `

Answer (score 0):

If `entry` is directly under `feed`, change the XPath query from `/rss/channel//item` to
 `/feed/entry`. (If it isn't, you'll need `/feed//entry`; note the double backslash.)

You'll also have to change the sorting function; I assume you'll want to sort according to `published`:

```
return strtotime($y->published) - strtotime($x->published);
```

Finally, modify the `foreach` loop to spit out the values you're interested in:

```
foreach ($entries as $entry) {
    echo $entry->title;
    echo $entry->content;
    echo $entry->published;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this, I need to have a combo of both xPaths. Is it possible to have like an operator in the xpath ?

Answer (score 0):

You could run 2 xpath's. If the first doesn't return any results, you try the second.

That may be the easiest and most pragmatic.